# Shadow DOM and <label for="id">

Tags: angular, web-component, angular2-template, shadow-dom

I'm having a simple component that has `<label for="...">` and `<input>` (a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gaWxLDUQK4lKhX8KUbFV?p=preview)):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'labeled-input',
  template: `
        <input id="labeled-input">
        <label for="labeled-input">input</label>
  `
})
class LabeledInputComponent {}
```

`id` is static, it serves to bind a label to related input.

Views are not encapsulated enough with default `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`, clicking on any label results in focusing on the first input.

Encapsulation works with `ViewEncapsulation.Native`, but only for supported browsers (Chrome)
(a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZdBTsUsgi6qTMGR2x1xQ?p=preview)).

Web Component Shadow DOM polyfill for `ViewEncapsulation.Native` doesn't differ from `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` here.

How can this case be treated?

Comment: Did you enable shadow DOM for webcomponents polyfill? Default is shady DOM. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings You can easily create unique ids dynamically to work around this emulation limitation.

Comment: Yes, I've tried ViewEncapsulation.Native + web-component polyfill (not web-component-lite) with no success. I'm not aware of how the polyfill works but I was hoping that it is more shaded than 'shady' DOM. So generating UIDs for `id` is common practice in this case? I guess that making `id` unique by mere +1 counter is not very practical because all component instances should be tracked.

Comment: You need to load full polyfill **and** explicitly enable shadow DOM. Default is shady DOM. See the link in my above comment.

Comment: I believe I did that (see [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/tqGDee0nNfJ46L33bCFG?p=preview)). Not sure if `window.Polymer` can affect A2, it looks like it is specific to Polymer. Still, no success in non-Chrome browsers with ViewEncapsulation.Native.